# Do I need to increase version name for auto update?

Tags: android

In my app, auto update doesn't work.

I found version name is still 1.0 though I've increase VersionCode from 1 to 2.

Do I need to increase version name for auto update?

Comment: Try searching what they really are in [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/regarding-version-code-and-version-name-android-manifest) or in the [Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) .

Answer (score 0):

The Android market takes about 5 hours to update your APK. If a user has auto update enabled for your application, only then would it update. However I am not entirely certain the version name makes a difference to this, I don't believe it does