# Releasing a new version of app in Google Play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

I released version 1.0 of my app into Google Play 8 days ago.  I want to release a small update -- version 1.01.  From reading this:

[versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/regarding-version-code-and-version-name-android-manifest)

I see that `versionCode` is only seen by users and `versionName` should be incremented one integer each time a new APK is uploaded.  I have the following questions:

1. For my situation, should I just update inside my `AndroidManifest` versionCode to `2` and versionName to `1.01`?
2. I have a `SQLite` db in my app but nothing has changed in it.  Should I update the db version in it regardless if anything changed or leave the same?
3. Other than changing versionCode, versionName and maybe the db version, is the only thing left to do is upload the new APK?

Below is the code to my `AndroidManifest`.

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="matt.lyons.bibletrivia.pro"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Comment: This helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16012992/upload-updates-on-google-play

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions:

> For my situation, should I just update inside my AndroidManifest versionCode to 2 and versionName to 1.01?

Yes.

AndroidManifest  is the only place you should do changes that are related to your app version. and the version number / name both make sense in your case.

> I have a SQLite db in my app but nothing has changed in it. Should I update the db version in it regardless if anything changed or leave the same?

Also no , DB versioning can be managed separatly from your app versioning. but whenever you want to update your DB you will have to apply 1 (update app version ).

> Other than changing versionCode, versionName and maybe the db version, is the only thing left to do is upload the new APK?

You are good to go. but don't forget to use [Proguard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to encrypt your code in the apk.