# Upload updates on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I developed an application. Which is having the SQLite Data base in assets folder. Then i uploaded the .apk on Google play.
Now i am having the updated data base of the same application.

So my issue is that:

**1. How to upload updated SQLite data base.**

Should i create new .apk and upload it.
If yes then :

**2. User has to download .apk again or they prompt only for updates?**

I am not clear with that. As up till now i just uploaded non updating application.
So please guide me for this.

Comment: Create a new apk with version number increased. And also in the SQLiteOpenHelper you have to change the version number of the database. (If you have created the db with queries in SQLiteOpenHelper class) In onUpgrade()add the new queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to upload updated SQLite data base. Should i create new .apk and
>   upload it.

=> As you are having static database by placing in `Assets` folder, you have to include updated database and upload the new APK signed with the same keystore.

> User has to download .apk again or they prompt only for updates?

=> Yes users will be notified for the app updates whenever you upload new APK for the same app.