# Android App Versioning

Tags: android, notifications, google-play

I have android app published in google play with the following version:

```
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0"
```

I think that's the default version when creating android app in Eclipse IDE. I made minor changes in my app. I want to publish the updated app. What is the recommended `versionCode` and `versionName` for the updated app?

What I want is that users who already installed the app will be notified by google play that a new version is available. Im new to android development. In my device, I received notification  for my installed app that there are new version available. I want this functionality.

I'm thinking of having:

```
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="1.0.1"
```

Is that OK?

thanks

Comment: Yes it is OK. As long as versionCode is incremented (+1), users will be notified about update. versionName is your format and you can use 1.0.1

Comment: Yes its absolutely right...  if you already have an application on play (market) and you want to change in existing code you need to do this steps.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes thats perfect.

> Typically, you would release the first version of your application
>   with versionCode set to 1, then monotonically increase the value with
>   each release, regardless whether the release constitutes a major or
>   minor release. This means that the android:versionCode value does not
>   necessarily have a strong resemblance to the application release
>   version that is visible to the user (see android:versionName, below).
>   Applications and publishing services should not display this version
>   value to users.
>
> As with android:versionCode, the system does not use this value for
>   any internal purpose, other than to enable applications to display it
>   to users. Publishing services may also extract the android:versionName
>   value for display to users.

Ref : [Versioning Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html) and [versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/regarding-version-code-and-version-name-android-manifest)

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's correct.
The versionCode needs to increment but the versionName can be any string to be shown to your users.
See docs for fuller explanation: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/versioning.html