# Is it possible to write a new code with same package name etc and the update an existing app if the code was somehow deleted.?

Tags: android, google-play, android-keystore

I wrote a code for an app which got deleted somehow. The thing is that I have the keystore and everything alse like earlier apk's but not the code. Is it possible to write a new code with same package name and update it over the old app.? Or is it somehow possible to update the app when I dont have its code.?

Comment: yes, just use the same keystore and package name and increment the version number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you develop the app with same package name and sign it with the same keystore, and increment the version appropriately then app should work as an update to the existing one i think.
[versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/regarding-version-code-and-version-name-android-manifest)

Comment: Thanx. It worked. Actually I tried it, but earlier it was giving certificate mismatch. But after you answered, the same thing worked. :) :)

Comment: Thats nice, now you know what to do when something perfectly fine does not work : p ) . Sometimes just a clean, build, export signed app again works.