# How to update version number of react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I am using React native with Android. How can I update version number in the app? As I am getting this error.

I am generating file as per this url
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html

I have tried modifying AndroidManifest.xml file, but after I build it, that file gets automatically modified back.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebook.react"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Here, I modified the XML:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.facebook.react"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

After, build file automatically changes back.

[image]

Comment: android:versionCode="2" mean whenever you want to upload apk on play store that is necessary to increase version code & version code you can keep whatever you want doesn't impact

Comment: doesn't work, I have already done it. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You should be changing your `versionCode` and `versionName` in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {

    defaultConfig {

        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        
        {...}
    }

    {...}
}
```

Note that `versionCode` has to be in an integer that is larger than the ones used for previous releases while `versionName` is the human readable version that may be shown to users.

Comment: Thanks, I myself saw that file multiple times, but just missed that part.

Comment: I found the solution in the file that you pointed to, but it was actually slightly further down. There was a section that started with **applicationVariants** and in there the **output.versionCodeOverride** was getting set, which did as the name suggested and overrode the one at the top of the file.

Comment: What about in AndroidManifest.xml do we need to update that?

Comment: @Noitidart if you're building with Android Studio and Gradle, changing it here will be enough. It will override anything you put in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: If I want my version to be "2.2" should I set versionCode to `2.2`? I don't understand `versionCode` :(

Comment: @Noitidart `versionCode` is a value that's meant for Google/you. When you upload to Google Play, it expects `versionCode` to be greater than the previous `versionCode`, and also unique for every uploaded file. Personally, I just manually increment `versionCode` by one each time I prepare an upload to Google Play. Other people automate it to increment based on the git commit, or other factor. `versionName` is what you would change to "2.2" so that your users will see that version number when they update/download your app.

Comment: Thank you sir very much for such an awesome explanation. @JosephRoque

Comment: must versionCode be a integer? 1.0.1 fails for me

Comment: @KTWorks yes, versionCode must be an integer. versionName can be set to `1.0.1` and will display that value to users.

Comment: For me it was enough to only increment `versionCode `

Answer (score 115):

@Joseph Roque is correct, you need to update the version numbers in `android/app/build.gradle`.

Here's how I automate this and tie it into the package's version in `package.json` and git commits.

In `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
/* Near the top */

import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def getNpmVersion() {
    def inputFile = new File("../package.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)
    return packageJson["version"]
}
/* calculated from git commits to give sequential integers */
def getGitVersion() {
    def process = "git rev-list master --first-parent --count".execute()
    return process.text.toInteger()
}


......


def userVer = getNpmVersion()
def googleVer = getGitVersion()

android {
...
    defaultConfig {
        .....
        versionCode googleVer
        versionName userVer

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Notes:

- It's important that `versionCode` is an integer - so we can't use semantic versioning here.  This is used on the play store to tell which versions come after others - that's why it's tied to git commits in `getGitVersion`
- `versionName` however is shown to users - I'm using semantic versioning here and storing the real value in my `package.json`. Thanks to https://medium.com/@andr3wjack/versioning-react-native-apps-407469707661

Comment: Andrew Jack discusses a very similar method, and a method for iOS in his Medium article: https://medium.com/@andr3wjack/versioning-react-native-apps-407469707661#.ky7l2lys7 . It is a great read for people wanting to keep their versions matching with their builds.

Comment: Does it mean that every time I used **git commit** the version changes incrementally? And which update type is incremented? I mean, will it start in the patch number?

Comment: @EdisonPebojot Yes, though only one of the versions will change.

There are two version types - the versionCode which must be incremental and is based on number of commits.  And the versionName which is taken from your package.json can be a string and is visible to the user.  You may want to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269683/1760776 for more details

Comment: Andrew Jack's article on Medium has been deleted. Here's his blog post on the topic, though: https://blog.andrewjack.uk/versioning-react-native-apps.

Comment: Need change master to main

`def process = "git rev-list main --first-parent --count".execute()`

Comment: I keep getting `../package.json (No such file or directory)`. I've tried changing to `../../` too, to no avail.

Answer (score 50):

For those wanting to automate this, and have iOS at the same time, you can use [react-native-version](https://github.com/stovmascript/react-native-version) to set the version numbers.

All you need to do is update your **version** number inside the package.json file and run the following:

```
$ npx react-native-version --never-amend

[RNV] Versioning Android...
[RNV] Android updated
[RNV] Versioning iOS...
[RNV] iOS updated
[RNV] Done
✨  Done in 0.39s.
```

I hope this can help others.

Comment: If you have ejected from expo, make sure the app.json is deleted otherwise the android and ios files will not get updated.

Comment: @bjorn-reppen Deleting app.json in Bare Workflow Expo projects is not the best solution, as App.json is still used by Expo (Updates for example)

The issue is being discussed here: https://github.com/stovmascript/react-native-version/issues/105

I patched react-native-version 4.0.0 as a temporary workaround until it gets fixed.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I checked all the above answer, I had a made a silly mistake because of which nothing worked for me. Just in case any of you do same mistake as mine try this.

1. **Version can be a decimal number like 1.0 or 1.0.1 etc**
2. But **VersionCode cannot be decimal number** It should be 1,2,3 etc and not 1.1 or 2.2

So in project/app/build.gradle

```
android {
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1 // do not use decimal number here
    versionName "1.0" // you can use decimal number here.
    {...}
}
{...}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the `versionCode` under `android` in app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "App Name",
...
    "android": {
      "package": "com.app.name",
      "permissions": [],
      "versionCode": 2
    }
  }
}
```

ref:https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/#versioncodeversion-number-required-by-google-play-increment-by-one-for-each-release-must-be-an-integer-httpsdeveloperandroidcomstudiopublishversioninghtml

Answer (score 1):

All these responses are more difficult than this should really be!

Even the "[React Native Version](https://github.com/stovmascript/react-native-version)" package is not up to the task. It forgets to update some files such as **info.plist**, suffers from pointless "SyntaxError" errors (which I can see people having issues getting around), and relies on deletion of **app.json** (which you may not wish to do) to update ejected expo projects properly.

Better to just manage your own scripted solution for versioning.

1. You can copy the node script from the gist link below to update the following files in a single command:

- package.json
- android/app/build.gradle
- ios/info.plist
- ios/app.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj

Link: https://gist.github.com/uxinnuendo/1be49a8faec7031044a87dcf79234cbd

2. Save to your root project folder and refer to the code comments to update the path references as appropriate for your project.
3. Then run:
   `$ node patch.js`
4. Modify the regex patterns to meet your project config files, since this can differ based on your react native / expo version. Some projects may have surrounding double quotes on version numbers, etc.

The script only deals with "patch" versioning for the moment, and is based on the following integer version format, both of which you can modify as you desire.

[SDK version: **xx**][Major version: **xx**][Minor version: **xxx**][Patch version: **xx**]

eg. 330100001

Answer (score 0):

If someone is facing

> wrong version code eg - 31284

Then make sure to not use SeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture in `android/app/build.gradle`

`def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false`

and

to update the version code and name change in `android/app/build.gradle`:

```
android {

defaultConfig {

    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    {...}
}

{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What @tgf has is good for Android, but I wanted ios as well. The default `Info.plist` sets `CFBundleShortVersionString` to `$(MARKETING_VERSION)`, which is the same as `versionName` in `android/build.gradle`, and `CFBundleVersion` is set to  `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`, which is the same as `versionCode` in `android/build.gradle`. These are defined in the `project.pbxproj` in `ios/AppName.xcodeproj/`. Here is a `prerelease` script that can update the xcode file. If you have modifications that have no been committed yet, it will add 1 to the build number so that building without any changes will not result in a file change.

```bash
yarn add glob --dev
```

```json
    "ios-update-version": "node scripts/iosUpdateVersion.js",
```

Use `pre` scripts to run this command.

`scripts/iosUpdateVersion.js`:

```js
const { globSync } = require('glob');
var fs = require('fs');
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const APP_VERSION = require('../package.json').version;
const GET_COMMIT_COUNT = 'git rev-list master --first-parent --count';

let BUILD_NUMBER = 0;

if (execSync('git status --porcelain').length) {
    console.log('increasing build number by one to include untracked changes');
    BUILD_NUMBER++;
}

const response = execSync(GET_COMMIT_COUNT).toString();
BUILD_NUMBER += Number.parseInt(response.trim());
// android (taken care of in build.gradle)
// versionCode googleVerver  // BUILD_NUMBER
// versionName userVer      // APP_VERSION
// ios
// CFBundleVersion CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = 1;            // BUILD_NUMBER
// CFBundleShortVersionString MARKETING_VERSION = 1.0;     // APP_VERSION
const plist = '/ios/SplitTheTank/Info.plist'
const xcodeprojs = globSync('ios/*.xcodeproj');
if (xcodeprojs.length === 0) {
    throw 'Could not find any xcodeproj folder'
}
const pbxproj = `${xcodeprojs[0]}/project.pbxproj`;
const data = fs.readFileSync(pbxproj, 'utf8');

let result = data.replace(/(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION = )(.*);/g, `$1${BUILD_NUMBER};`);
result = result.replace(/(MARKETING_VERSION = )(.*);/g, `$1${APP_VERSION};`);
fs.writeFileSync(pbxproj, result, 'utf8');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using **expo** and getting this issue, go to `app.json` and change the **version** to a higher number.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "nameofapp", // btw dont copy this
    "slug": "appslug",   // btw dont copy this
    "version": "1.0.0",  // here is where you change the version
    ...
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

You need to also change the **version** in `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "name": "appname",  // btw dont copy this
  "version": "2.0.0", // here is where you change the version
  ...
  "android": {
    "versionCode": 2,
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```