# How to update app version in Cordova

Tags: android, cordova, version

I've done this before, but quite a long time a go

For what I remember, setting version attribute in config.xml, that was it

The thing is that I had

```
<widget id="com.toniweb.appname" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

And changed to:

```
<widget id="com.toniweb.appname" version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

But when I upload the signed version to google play, I got this error:

> "El código de versión del APK debe ser superior a (Version of code must be greater than) 1100101008."

And searched in the code and yes, in fact, it isn't updated even if changing the version attribute

I build the .apk like this:

```
cordova prepare
cordova build --release android
```

And I sign it like this:

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHxxxxxxSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ../apk/android-release-unsigned.keystore  android-release-unsigned.apk appnameAndroidKey
android-release-unsigned.apk appname1.2.apk
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your `AndroidManifest.xml` and increase `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName`.To know how to increase you can go to this reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269683/5887638).

If you are using cordova make change in config.xml .As you previous version is 1.100111,Change it to 1.100112 or 1.200000.
 After that build your application again.

Comment: those did get updated, so I'm still confused, any other thought? thanks!

Comment: What is your previous version code and updated version code?

Comment: previous was 1.100111 and now is 1.2

Comment: Version code is integer.Make sure you are talking about version code.You can check in Android manifest.xml

Comment: it seems that the length of the version is relevant, then.. thanks for you help!

Answer (score -1):

Before copying platform files for building, first 
cleanup project from build artifacts : `cordova clean`

And after that build your project : `cordova build`

Maybe by cleaning old artifacts your problem will be solved.

Comment: Problem persisted + my apk folder was cleaned :(