# Your APK's version code should be higher than 378

Tags: android, cordova

I have created an Android app in Phonegap Build few months ago and its working fine and available on Play Store .I have Published Couple of updates of my app and thay are all Published Successfully but today i want to publish new update of my app but its showing the error **"Your APK Version code should be higher than 378 "**

[image]

I have changed Version in config file and also changed the android:version code and version name in AndroidManifest file but nothing working for me .
              Any help would be Appreciated .Thanks

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15593328/how-to-solve-your-apks-version-code-needs-to-be-higher-than-2-in-google-play

Comment: i checked this and tried all the solutions before asking question .but no solution helpful for me

Comment: Dearchive apk file and check that `versionCode` is correct. May be something wrong with apk builder

Comment: You need to change 'versionCode' to 379, in gradle.

Comment: in my project where i can find gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to update app version in Cordova](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38551198/how-to-update-app-version-in-cordova)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I think I have the same problem as you.

In production, i have The Following release:

> **200118** (2.0.11)

Note that the **6-digit versionCode**

I have **updated Cordova Client** (Cordova Android 5.2.1 and cordova@6.3.0)

I want to publish new release (my config.xml for the new version):

> Widget id = "com.xxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyy" version = "2.1.1"

When I compile the release with Cordova, I get a manifest:

> Manifest android: hardwareAccelerated = "true" android: versionCode =
>   "**20101**" android: versionName = "2.1.1"

Note that the **5-digit versionCode**

When I want to publish on Google Play, so I get the same message as you: "Your APK version code shoulds be Higher Than 200118"

Cordova bug?

As a workaround, **edit your config.xml**, add "android-versionCode" and specify your versionCode manually:

> widget id="com.xxxxx.yyyyyyyyyyy" android-versionCode="201018"
>   version="2.1.1"

And build

Comment: I added  android-versionCode="301018" Manually in my config file and No error .

Comment: You're a life saver Jerome!

Answer (score 0):

Your version in config.xml should be more than the previous one.Check my this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38551878/5887638)

Comment: I have made changes in my config.xml file and increased cersion from 4.0.0 to 4.1.1 .but again same Problem

Comment: after change have you build the application using cordova CLI?

Comment: and also changed Version code and Version name in androidmanifext file but again same error