# play store android version code must be higher - ionic app

Tags: ionic-framework, google-play, version

I did exactly as usual to publish my ionic app on the Play store. I updated all the version numbers in my config.xml to :

```
<widget android-versionCode="1830" id="com.XXXX" ios-CFBundleVersion="1830" 
ios-CFBundleVersionString="183" version="183" 
versionCode="10" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

I then build using `ionic package build android --release --profile profile_production`.
but I get an error message when I import the apk on the Play Store:
The version code must be higher ...

[image]

I tried to add this `android-versionCode="18308"` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38675269/2217647) but I get the same error.

Any ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Semantic Versioning ?

Rather than name it `1.0.8`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget id="com.XXXX" version="1.0.8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Once you have completed make sure you do a build

```
ionic build android
```

then

```
cordova build --release android
```

Comment: Thanks but LeRoy, I am at version 183 ! So I can (UNFORTUNATELY) back version to 1.XXX.  And I am building with ionic package.

Comment: @Louis I also noticed your not include release.... ionic package build PLATFORM_TAG --profile PROFILE_TAG --release