# How do you set the Android Build version (Using Xamarin)?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to publish my android application, and Google play is telling me the version number needs to be bumped by one (must be higher than 164). I have tried switching the Version name and version number, I have tried setting both higher than 165... I am not having any luck.

here is the error from Android 
[image]

And here is the settings in Xamarin

[image]

You can see I've tried flip flopping them, as well as bumping them up higher than just 165

Edit: This was not addressed by the difference between the version code and the version name, that information was correct. This was due to the number of digits for the version code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/versioncode-vs-versionname-in-android-manifest)

Comment: Where did you set the "Version Code"? Try to double-click your Android project in Xamarin Studio to open the Project Options. Then navigate to "Android Application". What does your "Version Number" say?

Comment: Sushi was close... You jogged my memory to something I had ran into years ago .. and that is the Version name must contain the same number of decimals 4.X.X must be 5.X.X in the next release you can't go from 4.X.X to 5.X ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, for anybody that finds this in the future; the problem was that the previous version of the application was version 4.8.11, and we were bumping to version 5 with a major release... Android wanted the version name to match the same pattern so switching to 5.0.0 fixed my problem.

Comment: Glad to know you found a solution

Comment: Very end of a long project ... fought me till the very end! :)