# Requirements for Android versionName

Tags: android

Are there requirements for `versionName` in Android? Can it be an arbitrary string, like Ubuntu’s releases (Bionic Beaver etc.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [versionCode vs versionName in Android Manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629125/versioncode-vs-versionname-in-android-manifest)

Answer (score 2):

There are no restrictions on choosing `versionName`. You can use "foo", "bar", "test-1", "release-2". Just string. This name is for showing user version, nothing else.

From **[Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning)**

> **versionName**
>
> - A string used as the version number shown to users. This setting can be specified as a raw string or as a reference to a string
>     resource.
> - The value is a string so that you can describe the app version as a    .. string, or as any other type of absolute or
>     relative version identifier. **The versionName has no purpose other
>
>     than to be displayed to users.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use any string you want for version name. There's no rule to this.

```
PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Version " + packageInfo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

That will show your package name.