# From where does the "Current Version" in the app Page gets displayed

Tags: android

Current Version in the App Page is pulled from release dashboard of play Store. Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: check the build.gradle file

Comment: build version is defined what you have mentioned in your gradle. check that.

Answer (score 0):

`build.gradle` file has typically structured like this:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ...
```

`versionName` is the version that displayed for all users. For more details you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269683/9060113).

Comment: Question was where is it in the compiled apk. There is no Gradle in the apk. It is in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have opened your project in `Android View`.

Then on you Left scroll to `Gradle Scripts` expand it.

Here you see `build.gradle(Project:name)` and `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Open `build.gradle(Module:app)`.

On Top of it. you will see

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.app_name"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1   //Change this to upgrade your app on PlayStore (Not shown there)
    versionName "1.1.0" //This was just to display on PlayStore
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: Question was where is it in the compiled apk. There is no Gradle in the apk. It is in the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the Android Manifest file. Though it's common to put it in the Gradle file, Android Gradle puts it into the Manifest file during compiling. The Manifest file starts off as a text file, but is compiled to binary.